# StartSignificantLocationChanges not launching the app in background iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

In iOS6 I was able to get locations with `StartSignificantLocationChanges`, even though the application was terminated by the user. However, what I have realized in iOS7 `StartSignificantLocationChanges` works well when I put my app into background but whenever I swipe to terminate it, It never gets launched in the background and continuing location updates. I have read some blogs claiming that the behavior has changed in iOS7 since terminating an app is user preference so that they respect the choice. However I couldn't find any official information on Location Programming Guide( Location programming guide still says that the system will relaunch the application that is registered for significant location changes). By the way, I'm testing my app over simulator and simulating the location freeway drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behavior has changed in iOS7 as you said. You can find detailed and official information in WWDC 2013 Session Videos #307 and #204.

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/